# How to search the current word in all opened tabs in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have started learning Vim word-search using `*` and `#` while the cursor is over the current word. But this search is limited to the current file buffer.

Is there a command or a shortcut to extend this search to:

1. all opened tabs?
2. all opened buffers?

Comment: You might find [this explanation of tabs vs. buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26710166/5419599) interesting and helpful.

Comment: buffers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975174/how-do-i-search-the-open-buffers-in-vim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have an exact solution for your problem, hopefully a better answer than mine will come up. But this is how I tackled the problem of finding a word in all buffers.

```
" enables to search in all open buffers with :Search <pattern>
command! -nargs=1 Search call setqflist([]) | silent bufdo grepadd! <args> %

nnoremap <left>  :cprev<cr>zvzz
nnoremap <right> :cnext<cr>zvzz
```

The first line creates a command `Search` with the search pattern as argument, which writes the results in a quickfix list. The two other lines map the (at least for me) useless arrow keys to something useful; they are mapped to jump to the next/previous Search or to the next/previous compile error, etc., they simply step throu the quickfix list. You can use this as follows:

```
:Search foobar
<right>
<right>
…
```

Comment: I love this command, but added a few things so it will escape search terms better, and force a redraw.  (using silent with splits can cause vim ui to bug out).  command! -nargs=1 Search call setqflist([]) | silent execute "bufdo grepadd! '<args>' %" | redraw!

Comment: you can also just type `:cn` or `:cp` to switch to the next document.

Answer (score 9):

It's actually the default behaviour although it may be hard to notice: try `*` then change to another tab and use `n` ans `N` in command mode to jump forward and backward between search hits.

This may make more sense if first you turn highlighting on for all hits:

```
:set hlsearch
```

Comment: +1 only because of `hlsearch` that I didn't know, and which I would have search for one day or another :-). However, by default I have tried * #, n and N, and **it doesn't jump to other file buffers**...

Comment: No, `n` and `N` do not jump buffers (they wrap around), but the term they target is searched for in all tabs; hit `*` with the highlighting on then cycle thru your tabs -- they will all be highlighted with the same term, so you can use `n` and `N` locally there without a fresh search.

Comment: The whole point is NOT to have to cycle through your tabs to find all the matches.

Comment: @Magnus While that may be preferable, it's actually not explicitly stated in the question, which asks how to *"extend this search to...all buffers"* -> it is extended across all buffers.  The point of my answer was to make this clear, since it might not be, especially if you do not have `hlsearch` set.

Answer (score 6):

```
 :bufdo vimgrepadd yoursearchterm % | copen
```

Answer (score 1):

As I've found myself frequently doing this I mashed up an (improvable) script.

You or someone else might find it useful.

---

#### Short explanation:

Basically it searches buffer list and show result in quickfix-window.

Two basic commands is added.

1. `Search <pattern>`  : Search all buffers for `<pattern>`.
2. `Search1 <pattern>` : Search all buffers for `<pattern>`, but only show first result for each buffer. Typically useful for listing all buffers where function, variable `foo` is used, (or what ever).

Use bang (`:Search! foo`) to append to results.

Additionally `GSearch` and `GSearch1` is added where difference is that with `Search` the script add regex delimiter, e.g.:

```
foo -> /foo/
```

Where as `GSearch` expect it to be enclosed.

The `j` flag is always added to prevent jump.

---

#### Code:

There are some hacks to prevent error listing while at the same time keeping the code short. `try / catch` was a bit cumbersome on `bufdo`.

```vim
let s:not_idents = split("/!#$%&\"`´¨'¯()*+,-.:;<=>?¿@[\]^{|}µ¶·¸~±×÷®©«»¬­ª°º¹²³¼½¾", '\zs')
" Create a delimited pattern. "
fun! s:Parse_pat(pat)
    for c in s:not_idents
        if stridx(a:pat, c) == -1
            return c . a:pat . c
        endif
    endfor
    echohl Error
    echom "Could not delimit pattern '". a:pat ."'"
    echohl None
    return ''
endfun

fun! s:AllBufSearch(pat, bang, uno, isg)
    if a:isg
        let pat = a:pat
    else
        let pat = s:Parse_pat(a:pat)
    endif
    if pat == ''
        return
    endif
    cclose
    let [_buf, _view] = [bufnr("%"), winsaveview()]
    let _foldenable = &foldenable
    set nofoldenable

    " Copy of current qflist. "
    let qfc = getqflist()
    " Hack to prevent error if no matches. "
    call setqflist([{}])
    silent execute "bufdo vimgrepadd! " . pat . "j %"
    " Restore "
    exec "buffer " . _buf
    let &foldenable = _foldenable
    call winrestview(_view)
    " Fix "
    let qf = getqflist()
    call remove(qf, 0)
    " Only one listing per buffer. "
    if a:uno
        let bn = {}
        let i  = 0
        for m in qf
            if has_key(bn, m["bufnr"])
                call remove(qf, i)
            else
                let bn[m["bufnr"]] = 1
                call remove(qf[i], "valid")
                let i += 1
            endif
        endfor
    endif
    if a:bang == "!"
        let qf = qfc + qf
    endif
    " If any matches, copen. "
    if len(qf)
        call setqflist(qf)
        copen
    endif
endfun

command! -nargs=1 -bang Search   call s:AllBufSearch(<q-args>, "<bang>", 0, 0)
command! -nargs=1 -bang Search1  call s:AllBufSearch(<q-args>, "<bang>", 1, 0)
command! -nargs=1 -bang GSearch  call s:AllBufSearch(<q-args>, "<bang>", 0, 1)
command! -nargs=1 -bang GSearch1 call s:AllBufSearch(<q-args>, "<bang>", 1, 1)
```